# Jquery Get longdesc Prop

Tags: jquery, prop

I need to get the longdesc from an image.

I have tried:

```
$(this).prop('longdesc');
```

but it returns undefined.

Comment: you could try `.attr()` instead of `.prop()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just for the sake of an answer:

Use `attr()` instead of `prop()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data-*` attributes, and get the data using `.data()`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: An interesting idea. I will think about this for the future, but I'll stick with attr('longdesc') for now.